# Why should I write "@Override"?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

I tried to write my code with and without the syntax "`@Override`", and both times I receive the same output. Therefore, why should I bother to write the syntax "`@Override`" before my method in the subclass?

With:
[image]

Without:
[image]

Comment: Please [**search**](/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+what+is+%40override+for) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
hey there, I couldn't find previous exploitation... maybe I should improve my search skills... still learning how to find information... until then...  could you please add a link to a previous post that answer my question?

Comment: Actually search engine on this site isn't very useful (unless you already know what you are looking for or the answer). Google usually provides better results if we specify we want to limit it to this site via `site:stackoverflow.com` flag. In your case you can use query like `site:stackoverflow.com why use override in java`